# JQuery mobile style failure

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I am designing the web page and use JQuery mobile. I want that page consist of several parts (sub pages) alowing it to work without internet connection (i.e. after page was fully loaded you can switch between sub-pages without reload).
My single page structure is

```
<div id="page" data-role="page">
            <div id="header">
                <a href="#menu"></a>
                // menu
            </div>
            <div id="content">
                // content
            </div>
            <nav id="menu">
                // menu
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Everything here works alright. 
Now I am adding second page (same html document):

```
<div id='full_screen_wr'>
        <div data-role="page" id="foo">
          <div data-role="header" data-close-btn="right">
             <h1>Dialog</h1>
             sdfsdlfjslkdjkl
          </div>
          <input type="submit" value="Click me~" />
        </div>
         <input type="submit" value="Click me~" />
    </div>
```

(I will explain why it is wrapped in 'full_screen_wr' later).
I employ mmenu (mmenu.frebsite.nl) and here comes the problem. I tried to make this second page (id="foo") to show as dialog and it failed. Why - I have no idea, but it is linked with mmenu. I was not able to find the issue, so I decided to implement dialog interface myself. So I put the second page (id="foo") inside wrapper with absolute position above:

```
#full_screen_wr
{
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #FFF; 
    display:none;
}
```

On button click, I do `$("#full_screen_wr").show();` and it shows white screen with button. But button has no JQuery mobile style. My main page has buttons and elements in JQuery mobile style. Here I have no style at all.

I am new to JQuery Mobile. What is wrong there?

Or How to make full screen dialog with JQuery Mobile style without ajax or page reloading?

I am using Google Desktop Chrome for testing. 
Thanks for ideas.

Comment: If you're using JQM 1.4 add `data-dialog="true"` attribute to `foo` page div. Don't forget to remove the wrapper.

Comment: I tried. No result. Standart JQuery dialog for some reason does not want to work.

Comment: How do you call it? If you're using JQM 1.4 it should work. It shouldn't be wrapped in any div,just like a normal page.

Comment: https://github.com/BeSite/jQuery.mmenu/issues/103

Comment: yes, it should work, but it do not. Can I manually apply JQuery mobile style to elements?

Comment: Then the error is caused by the plugin you're using. Anyway, style elements `$("#foo").enhanceWithin();`.

Comment: Thanks. It looks like this function what was needed. I achived same result by manual assing class='ui-btn ui-input-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow' to elements, but your solution is much nicer!

Comment: But still some issue with that: in both cases, I get black and white scheme, while main page in grey with shadows. Can I change it somehow? And `$("#full_screen_wr").enhanceWithin();`! Stuff with '#foo' give not desired result.

Comment: Sure it will work on any div. add data-theme to food div or its' wrapper.

Comment: Thanks! If you want, you can make `enhanceWithin` as answer and I will  tick and voteup it :)